# Spring Data JPA - Multiple Persistence Units working as JUnit, but not in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am nearly ready to fall back to my comfortable JDBC Template use for this one, but thought I'd see if the community has any insight. I added a 2nd set of JPA framework objects to my Spring-based application: new Entity Manager, Persistence Unit, etc. The exising Entity Manager uses ObjectDB for persistence and I want to use the slick Spring Data JPA API for a CRUD repository (Hibernate as an impl) but it's giving me trouble all along the way. I thought I had resolved everything locally b/c I had a JUnit that got past bean creation, but once I dropped those beans into an applicationContext I had a regression that I do not know how to fix

JUnit and Application context XML snippet with company name removed from the com.xxx

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.dms.server.mode" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>
<!-- TxMgr #1 -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
<!-- EMF #1 -->
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernate-pu" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence-hibernate.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="sharedModeManager" class="com.dms.server.mode.DefaultSharedModeManager"/>
<bean id="changeRecordCommandFactory" class="com.dms.server.ChangeRecordCommandFactory"/>

<bean id="createModeCommand" class="com.dms.server.mode.CreateModeCommand">
    <property name="apsConnection" ref="ApsConnection" />
</bean>

<!-- TxMgr #2 -->
<bean id="EnvDMSTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="EnvDMSEntityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<!-- EMF #2 -->
<bean id="EnvDMSEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="envService"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="com.objectdb.jpa.Provider"/>
</bean>
```

persistence-hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="hibernate-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-none.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>com.api.dms.SharedMode</class>
    <class>com.api.dms.SharedModeAssignment</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="envService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>com.objectdb.jpa.Provider</provider>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/orm-objectdb.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>com.awareness.server.environment.SampleIndicationHistory</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="$temp/awp/envService.odb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

orm-none.xml (everything is picked up via annotations, but if I don't specify this file, the other orm file is picked up)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
</entity-mappings>
```

orm-objectdb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
<entity class="com.awareness.server.environment.SampleIndicationHistory" access="FIELD">
    <table name="SAMPLE_IND_HISTORY"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="deviceId"/>
        <basic name="tOldest"/>
        <basic name="tNewest"/>
        <element-collection name="timestamps"/>
        <element-collection name="indexes"/>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Again, this all works fine and dandy in a JUnit

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/com/junit-context.xml"})
// Functioning JUnit
```

But fails in Tomcat with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sharedModeManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sharedModeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.api.dms.SharedMode
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sharedModeRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.api.dms.SharedMode
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1454)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:249)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:442)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.api.dms.SharedMode
at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:171)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:146)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:84)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:67)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:150)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
... 51 more
```

Java Classes

```
@Repository
@PersistenceContext(unitName="hibernate-pu")
public interface SharedModeRepository extends CrudRepository<SharedMode, SharedModeKey> {
Iterable<SharedMode> findByName(String name);
Iterable<SharedMode> findByCurrent(boolean current);
SharedMode findBySharedModeKeyIdAndCurrent(int id, boolean current);
}

@PersistenceContext(name="hibernate-pu")
@Entity(name="shared_mode")
@XmlRootElement(name="sharedMode")
public class SharedMode implements Comparable<SharedMode>, ModeLike, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3202319961514321359L;
    @EmbeddedId
    @XmlElement
    private SharedModeKey sharedModeKey = new SharedModeKey();
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private boolean current;
    ...
}
```

It's hard to know what is done differently in the start-up to make things fail, I've been stepping through a lot of framework code trying to determine exactly what goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The last exception you get means JPA provider can not identify your bean. As you are using Spring, you can set `packagesToScan` property on the `entityManagerFactory` to the package which contains your entities to enable JPA provider to find them. Alternatively you can use `persistence.xml` and list all entities there.

Comment: Ean, please see `persistence-hibernate.xml`, I do list out the bean being complained about in the stacktrace

Comment: Try putting them in persistence.xml as there was an old bug in Spring related to these JPA config files. (I don't remember what was that at the moment)

Comment: It ended up being an error in my setup, where the entities where in on JAR and the persistence.xml was in another JAR.